# Main reason for data loss in structured spark streaming

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, aws-glue

We have deployed an application that subscribes to around 20 Kafka topics using foreachbatch and write  as parquet with append using repartition and partitionBy. We have noticed that we get data loss on one or more of the partitions and have no clue of why. Anyone experienced the same thing and what did you do?

Basically using the default configuration and glue 4 with pyspark.

have tried to persist the data.

Comment: little data provided. watermarking?

Comment: Don’t seem to be related to late data since timestamp is almost the same and the published time. Glue throws failed to write rows, and usually it’s one file partition that has failed